# Two-way data binding: Unable to change EditText value when value updated from an inner class

Tags: java, android, data-binding

I am trying to update the value in my EditText by calling `profile.setClientName("Name");` from an `Observer<T>`'s `onChanged` event, but the EditText doesn't reflect the changes.
The EditText updates if the above line of code is called from the `onCreateView` of  my fragment.

Here's my code:

ClientProfileFragment.java

```
public class ClientProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ClientProfile profile; //The BaseObservable 
    private CPViewModel mViewModel;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        ClientProfileFragmentBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,
            R.layout.client_profile_fragment, container, false);
        clientProfileView = binding.getRoot();

        profile = new ClientProfile();
        binding.setClientprofile(profile);

        final Observer<ClientProfile> clientProfileObserver = new Observer<ClientProfile>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ClientProfile clientProfile) {
            profile.setClientName("Name"); //This line gets executed. Confirmed.
            }
        };
        mViewModel.getClientProfile().observe(this, clientProfileObserver);

        //If I call profile.setClientName("Name"); from here then the corresponding
        //EditText changes to "Name".

        return clientProfileView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        customerFindFuture.then(new FutureCallback<Response<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<String> result) {

                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
                ClientProfileWrapper clientProfileWrapper =
                            gson.fromJson(result.getResult(), ClientProfileWrapper.class);

                profile = clientProfileWrapper.getData().get(0);
                mViewModel.getClientProfile().setValue(profile);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ClientProfile.java

```
public class ClientProfile extends BaseObservable {
    private String clientName;

    public ClientProfile() {
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }

    public void setClientName(String clientName) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.clientName);
    }
}
```

CPViewModel.java

```
public class CPViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<ClientProfile> clientProfile;

    public MutableLiveData<ClientProfile> getClientProfile() {
        if (clientProfile == null) {
            clientProfile = new MutableLiveData<>();
        }
        return clientProfile;
    }
}
```

client_profile_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout2">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="clientprofile"
            type="com.package.ClientProfile" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/name_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/name_label">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/name_input"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="textPersonName"
                            android:text="@={clientprofile.clientName}"/>
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: share your viewmodel class

Comment: what is the event that triggers the `onChanged` in your observer?

Comment: @MehulKabaria updated.

Comment: @Onheiron I'm fetching ClientProfile data online. Once the json is de-serialized, I am calling `mViewModel.getClientProfile().setValue(deserializedClientProfile);`.

Comment: what about your `mViewModel` class? It seems like you're doing one too many set operations, either you set the new `ClientProfile` value or you set the new name value.

Comment: The mViewModel is a completely different class which extends ViewModel. I am using the mViewModel only to trigger the Observer (also from an inner class). It might look like I am repeating operations, but for simplicity, I have edited my code here and excluded the mViewModel class.

Comment: it extends the Android `ViewModel` class? Seems like a mix of databinding features here: if you're using `LiveData` with Android `ViewModel` you should bind your xml to that view model and have its fields like `clientName: MutableLiveData<String>...`.

Comment: I've updated the Fragment Code and added ViewModel code for reference. Also, I am unable to understand your instructions.

Comment: `profile = clientProfileWrapper.getData().get(0);` in the fragment is causing the problem. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had to call `binding.setClientprofile(profile);` after assigning value to `profile` 
e.g.

```
profile = clientProfileWrapper.getData().get(0);
binding.setClientprofile(profile);
notifyPropertyChanged(BR._all);
```

Doing this populated the EditText field with the current required value.